# ImportError: cannot import name 'Optional' from 'torch.jit.annotations'

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, torchvision

I have installed cpuonly pytorch and torchvision in anaconda. But when i try to import torchvision i get the following error.

ImportError: cannot import name 'Optional' from 'torch.jit.annotations'(C:\Users\MSI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\jit\annotations.py)
How can i fix this?

Comment: Would you try checking the versions of pytorch and torchvision.
Their versions should correspond to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are installing the correct versions of the libraries. This combination seems to work:

```
conda create --name test5 python=3.6
conda install -c pytorch pytorch torchvision cpuonly
python
>>> import torchvision
```